# php/mysql merge duplicate records in table and create a new table

Tags: php, mysql

please with respect to username and storetype, how can I merge rows to achieve Final table? storetype should be unique per username. There are thousands of usernames and records so php/mysql would help.
thanks
[image]

Comment: What do you want to do if one of the columns has a value in more than one row?

Comment: storetype should only appear once per username

Comment: So it doesn't matter which one is kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select min(id), username, min(filename), min(date), min(desc), storetype,
 min(password), min(email), min(ftp)
 from table1
 group by username, storetype
```

thanks to @Mosty Mostacho

Answer (score 0):

Since only the storetype matter, just run through the table for every username storing the details in variables which are not null. After that run an alter table command to update only one row with these values in the variables and then delete the other rows.
You could also use certain Normalization rules to first break up the table and rejoin them back up again. It could be less efficient though.